# Markdown is not rendering with Angular's data-binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, markdown

I am using an example from this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/u54Kh/) . What I am trying to achieve it to dynamically populate the date in my Angular's ng-repeat. The example is a working example but it is not working with data-binding. Below are my code:

JS

```
.directive('markdown', function () {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.text()); //Prints out {{post.article}}
            var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(element.text());
            element.html(htmlText);
        }
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <div markdown>{{post.article}}</div> <!-- Output: ##Testing -->
    <div markdown>**Testing**</div>      <!-- Output: <strong>Testing<strong>-->
</div>
```

In the comment of that code is the result. The first output didn't went as expected. What have I done wrong here or am I missing something?

Note from Console

```
outerHTML: "<div markdown="" class="ng-binding"><p>{{post.article}}</p></div>"
outerText: "{{post.article}}↵↵"

outerHTML: "<div markdown=""><strong>Testing</strong></div>"
outerText: "Testing↵"
```

**Note: Check the comment out in the JS, console.log(element.text());**

Comment: `The first output didn't went as expected.`: how is it actually going? I suggest you putting the erroneous code in JSFiddle as well.

Comment: Check [ng-showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/ng-showdown) and use it instead of your current directive.

Comment: @Joy I have added the output from console.log

Comment: @YAAK , I'll check on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative to my solution:

included [Angular Sanitize Js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-sanitize.min.js) and [Markdown Converter Js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Converter.js)

JS

```
$scope.converter = new Markdown.Converter();
$scope.convert = function(markdown) {
    return $scope.converter.makeHtml(markdown);
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="convert(post.article)"></div>
```